# Don't work https requests on MacBook using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

I have an API that is using `aiohttp` to make requests. I develop on Windows PC and there it worked. In Docker it also works. But I tried run on Mac with M2 and got error. This is script and below the error:

```python
import asyncio
import requests

import aiohttp


def req():
    return requests.get(
        "https://filfox.info/api/v1/address/f410f3m5x7kztwu7jklruoqehdgvy442jwhlhy7wr4oy").json()


async def f():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(
                "https://filfox.info/api/v1/address/f410f3m5x7kztwu7jklruoqehdgvy442jwhlhy7wr4oy") as response:
            res_json = await response.json()
            print(res_json)
            return res_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("FROM AIOHTTP")
    try:
        asyncio.run(f())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"ERROR: {ex}")
    print("FROM REQUESTS")
    print(req())
```

Error is following:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to host filfox.info:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')]
```